# The game keeps freezing. Help?

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v

Every time I try to play GTA 5, it freezes on me. I can't even get past the first mission without it doing it. I tried to uninstall and reinstall it, and the same thing still happens. I tried different copies of the game, and the same thing still happens. I'm playing the Xbox 360 version. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling the installation disk. It might be a corrupt installation.

Comment: I tried that already didnt work.

Comment: Does this ever happen with other games on your Xbox or just with GTA V?

Comment: Make sure you have at least 500MB space. Clear your cache. Check the files for corrupted files.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue, and the fix for me was to only install the install disc, and play the game from the other disc. Rockstar informed about this bug, saying it was some related to some texture-streaming issue (if i recall correctly).

(This should maybe have been a comment, but since I don't have the rep to write comments yet it will have to be an answer)